# Using data from .xsd file in xslt 1.0 file

Tags: xml, xslt, xsd

In my xsd file I have a simple type which contains an enumeration.

```
<xs:simpleType name="genreTyp">
  <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
    <xs:enumeration value="Sci-Fi"/>
    <xs:enumeration value="Horror"/>
    <xs:enumeration value="Drama"/>
    <xs:enumeration value="Romance"/>
    <xs:enumeration value="Comedy"/>
    <xs:enumeration value="Bollywood"/>
  </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

looking like this.

I'm using XSLT 1.0 and would like to create a table that displays those different values. How do I access the values using XSLT 1.0?

Edit: I'm still relatively new at XSLT so I tried accessing the xsd file with a path like this:

```
<xsl:for-each select="document('xsd/attributes.xsd' )/xs:schema/xs:simpleType[@name='genreTyp']/xs:restriction/xs:enumeration">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="//@value"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: `<xsl:value-of select="//@value"/>` makes no sense. Try `<xsl:value-of select="@value"/>` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're close - assuming the things you haven't shown us, like namespace declarations, are correct -- but that leading "//" in the xsl:value-of is nonsense. You want to select relative to the context node (the one selected in the for-each), not relative to the root of the tree, so leave out the "//".

Comment: Yes this worked well, thank you! Thanks for hinting me towards the namespace declaration too, since initially that was wrong too in my code.

Answer (score 0):

This could serve you as a starting point, [demo](https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/gWmuiKq).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  version="1.0">

  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" html-version="5"/>

  <xsl:template match="xs:enumeration">
    <tr><td><xsl:value-of select="@value"/></td></tr>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="xs:restriction">
      <table><xsl:apply-templates/></table>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- ignore space only text nodes -->  
  <xsl:template match="text()">
      <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

resulting in

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<table xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <tr>
      <td>Sci-Fi</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Horror</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Drama</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Romance</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Comedy</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Bollywood</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```